# Probability involving drawing balls

Tags: probability

An urn contains 7 red and 6 white balls. Players Beavis and Butthead alternately take turns drawing a ball until a player selects a red ball. What is the probability that the player who selects first will win?

Comment: With or without replacement?

Comment: @bof Without replacement

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(n)$ be the probability that the first player to play, as $n$ white balls remain, wins.

We have $$
p(n) = \frac{7}{n+7}\times 1 + \frac{n}{n+7}\times(1-p(n-1))\\p(0) = 1
$$
(according to the result of the first turn).

From this it should be easy.

Comment: Could you explain to me the recurrence relation and how you came about getting it?

Comment: after the first player played, he either wins with proba 7/(n+7) or the other one plays.

Comment: in oter words: just use the formula $P(A) = P(A\cap B^c) + P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Could you work out a few numbers, and let me know what your final answer, should you need to calculate p(6). I am in my way of thinking and kind of trying to figure out the answer.  Could you also comment on my method?

Comment: @mookid So do we need to add up the resulting probabilities?

Comment: no, you just look for $p(6)$ which is your result.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
Assume that Beavis starts the game.
P(Beavis picking the red ball in his first try) = $$7/13$$

P(Both of them do not pick the red ball and Beavis picks it at the 2nd try) = $$(6/13)(5/12)(7/11) = \frac{{7\choose3}}{{13\choose3}}$$

Keeps going and the probability that the first player to pick red wins before all white balls run out  =

Required Probability = $$\sum_{i=1,3,5,7}\dfrac{{7\choose i}}{{13\choose i}} = 0.677738928$$

Comment: This is incorrect. You're including all the events in which the second player wins as well. What you've calculated is the probability that the game doesn't require 13 draws. Beyond that, do you know if there is any combinatorial significance for each event having a probability equal to a quotient of two binomial coefficients?

Comment: I suspected that it is wrong.  I understood that question to be that the player who picks the red ball wins and I thought it does not matter if it is Beavis or Butthead.  Also, I was thinking that you should include all the events of both players winning till all the white balls have been drawn.  Let me know the correct answer

Comment: I misspoke before.  You didn't calculate the probability that it takes fewer than thirteen draws; rather, you calculated the probability that it takes fewer than *seven* draws, which is the longest the game can go on as it is.  Think of it this way: Since there is a maximum of seven rounds, you can find the probability of each event:  The game ends in one round, the game ends in two, etc.  You've already (at least implicitly) found these probabilities.  In which events does the first player win?

Comment: Does it mean that I should run i with a step 2.  Put it in other words, I should only calculate the probability that Beavis wins until the White ball runs out.  Thanks for helping me out.  This has clarified the issue, I was thinking that it could be any one who picks the red ball first.  This is different from a game where Beavis or Butthead wins with whosoever starts the game.

Comment: @romaldohowo.  The changed the solution and it is in agreement with MooKid